# Auto-comment questions with lack of code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, code

There is many questions on the StackOverflow from a new members where it is impossible to answer until OP will show some code and specify failing line. Currently we are writing the same comments under posts like this. Would be nice to be able to flag such posts to allow system inform OP automatically. It could be the same universal comment from the *Community* user for example.

UPDATE:
I know about `Not a real question` voting. My point is that maybe there is no need to go through all this voting to close than voting to reopen process when we can make it faster.

Comment: You can already flag such questions as *Not a real question*.

Comment: @juergend but this will close the question, making OP ask again, when a small comment could give him an answer much faster

Comment: I have the sense you aren't talking about "flagging" as it's generally understood on SE. You're talking about an automatic comment, right? Not the sort of flags that go to moderators and review queues?

Comment: @cpast right, seems like that was a bad choice of word

Comment: Also consider that not all questions require a code sample to be a good question. I think that making it easy to auto-comment will make it less likely that you actually look at the context of the post and determine if, in reality, it *needs* a code sample. In which case the auto-comments will be just as much noise as the comments that took you 20 seconds to write.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a question is incomplete and vague (code or not), then you should flag or vote to close the question as Not A Real Question.

That is plenty enough, really.

The point of closing questions is that a question poster that does not include code is not always going to put in the work to improve the question after the fact either. I rather reopen a question that was improved, than not close a question because it *might* be improved with a comment.

If you really find that you have to type the same comment over and over again, use the [AutoReviewComments script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). Just make sure you don't overuse auto-comments; we don't need more noise in comments either.

Comment: nice, exactly what i was talking about, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can already flag such questions as *Not a real question*.

Only generating a comment through a flag would be a misuse of the flagging system IMO. Flagging is voting for a specific action and not just for generating a comment.

If you want to save time typing a comment, then use a snippet.